# Twos pointers reflects the same value but with different address( C language)

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-address

I created a function to return the pointer as follows:

```
int* function(int cc){
    int* p;
    p=&cc; 
    return p;
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int *p1;
    a=10;
    p1=&a;
    printf("value for *p1 = %d\r\n",*p1);
    printf("value for *function  %d\r\n", *function(a));
    printf("pointer p1 = %p\r\n", p1);
    printf("pointer function= %p\r\n", function(a));

    return 0;
}
```

The console log is shown as follows:

```
value for *p1 = 10
value for *function  10
pointer p1 = 0x16d4bb1f8
pointer function= 0x16d4bb1dc
```

I really don't understand why two pointers could show the same value, but the address they stored are different.

Comment: You code has Undefined Behaviour. `p=&cc;` points to a *local variable* that is  only valid within the function. Dereferencing a pointer to it outside the function is UB.

Comment: Your second pointer points not at `a`, but at the local variable `cc`, that's why it's different. And, by the way, that code works only by accident, because using a pointer at a local variable after the function returns yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: @bereal, it isn't true that it works only by accident. UB under the standard doesn't mean that the behavior is random/chance/accident, unless the compiler is non-deterministic. Plenty of things that are UB under the standard are, in fact, actually IDB.

Comment: @torstenvl can you guarantee that if it works for the OP, it will work with e.g. any different compilation flags in the same compiler?

Comment: @bereal, no, I can't, but that's irrelevant. The vast vast majority of things in existence are not guaranteed -- that doesn't mean they are "by accident." Your point is overstated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you have passed in the function is done as a parameter (normal variable and not a pointer). If you really want the it should work like you expect then you should pass pointer instead of a normal int local variable.

Make these changes:

```
int* function(int *cc){
    int* p;
    p=cc; 
    return p;
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int *p1;
    a=10;
    p1=&a;
    printf("value for *p1 = %d\r\n",*p1);
    printf("value for *function  %d\r\n", *function(&a));
    printf("pointer p1 = %p\r\n", p1);
    printf("pointer function= %p\r\n", function(&a));

    return 0;
}
```

This code works and shows the output that you expect... We did this as we don't  want a new copy of the variable passed into the function. We want the same address and so we should pass variable address in the function.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
void function(int cc){
    int* p;
    p=&cc; 
   cc = 42; // just for fun
   printf("value of cc inside function  %d\r\n", cc);
  printf("value of &cc %p\r\n", &cc);
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int *p1;
    a=10;
    p1=&a;
    function(a);
    printf("value for *p1 = %d\r\n",*p1);
    printf("pointer p1 = %p\r\n", p1);
    return 0;
}
```

you will see that cc is a copy of a, if you change its value inside 'function' it does not change 'a'. You have found c's 'call by value' semantics. Meaning that variables are passed as copies to functions.

Comment: `printf("value of &cc %d\r\n", &cc);`: `%d` is not a correct format specifier to print a pointer. The correct way to print a pointer is using `%p` with a cast to `void *`.

Comment: @JASLPdoesn'tsupporttheIES - cut n paste oops - ty